# jquery $.session плагин

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Может кто знает, как в js плагине [$.session](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin) получить значение, например такого массива $_SESSION['user']['id']?

Пытался сделать так:

```
$.session.get('user');
И так:
$.session.get('user').get('id');
```

Comment: Попробуйте так $.session.get('user.id');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это плагин обеспечивает доступ к объекту `window.sessionStorage`, который позволяет хранить некоторые данные в формате `ключ: значение` на стороне пользователя (в браузере).

Данный плагин не имеет никакого отношения к сессиям PHP и массиву `$_SESSION`

Если Вам на клиенте нужно получить доступ к этому массиву, то Вы должны реализовать свой протокол чтения/записи. Например, при помощи Ajax